# Kernel 4.12.3 doesn't coop with bcmwl-kernel-source (Mint 18.2)

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, firmware

I updated my kernel to fix a problem with a graphics driver (namely AMDGPU-PRO from AMD) and it works like a dream now

However, if you fix one problem - another problem will arise.
The bcmwl-kernel-source (WiFi driver for the AC1900 wireless card)
doesn't seem to work at all?

Usually on the 4.10.1.27 kernel on Linux Mint 18.2, (I have no clue how to solve *this* problem) I have to re-install the WiFi drivers on reboot. using

```
sudo apt install--reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And it works as if nothing is wrong, tested it 4 hours straight and got a solid 8 megabytes/s peak.

Other information that I wouldn't mind speaking of:
The PCIe ID is 14e4:43e0 / BCM4360

These were the error logs when trying to do re-install
 [whycan'tnewlyregisteredpeopleputpictureshere >:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDu8J.png)

And I'm using a computer that I've built, and the specs are:

- GA-Z270X UD5 motherboard
- i7 7700k (kabylake) CPU
- RX 560 graphics card
- Crucial ballistix elite 2666MHz (2 x 8gb kit) memory
- TP-link Archer T9E AC1900 (aka the problematic card) wifi card

I'm also very new to Linux. so please go easy on me :p

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem as well after upgrading from 4.10 to 4.12.3 to fix an audio issue.

What I did to fix the problem was revert back to 4.10, and then just upgrade to 4.11.12 instead.

> sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.12.3*
>
> sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.12.3*

It fixed my audio issue and played nice with the wifi driver.

Seems like either 4.12 or bcmwl-kernel-source don't support one another yet.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Latest bcmwl-kernel-source now supports kernel 4.12 and 4.13.

To download and install latest:

`wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb`

Then rebuild your kernels with new module:
`ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools | sudo xargs -n1 /usr/lib/dkms/dkms_autoinstaller start`